# Getting the values from a checkbox listitems

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a checkbox list items which dynamically gets created based on database resultset. Now I want to get all the selected values back in a comma delimited list.

XAML

```
        <ListBox  x:Name="lstCategory"  Grid.Column="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115" Margin="291,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125" ItemsSource="{Binding EnvItems}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <CheckBox Margin="5,2"
                                  IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </CheckBox>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>




private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


    string a, b;

    a = lstCategory.SelectedItems.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

Comment: What is `EnvItems` exactly? What is a selected "value" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TemplateBinding is OneWay. To make it TwoWay:

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}">
```

Then you will get data in SelectedItems:

To get a commaseparated string:

```
    string x = string.Join(",", lstCategory.SelectedItems.OfType<string>());
```

Comment: thanks RolandJS. Worked a treat. I had like to understand what you did, please point me at some useful items to read. I am very grateful.

Comment: This link will give you some more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
string a = string.Join(",", lstCategory.SelectedItems.Cast<CheckBox>().Select(x => x.IsChecked));
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed answer, when I tried it it was just blank.

Answer (score 1):

1. Bind the `IsSelected` property to a property of your data class using the `{Binding}` markup extension:

   ```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <CheckBox Margin="5,2" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </CheckBox>
    </ControlTemplate>
   ```

The data class would be defined something like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

2. Retrieve all items with the data-bound source property set to true:

   ```
    IEnumerable<string> selectedNames = lstCategory.SelectedItems
        .OfType<YourClass>()
        .Where(x => x.IsSelected)
        .Select(x => x.Name);

    string s = string.Join(",", selectedNames);
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much